# Is there a Postgres equivalent to Oracle %TYPE?

Tags: sql, oracle, postgresql

In Oracle, if I needed to declare something with the same type as another column, I can simply use %type.

```
   copiedType OTHER_TABLE.COLUMN_NAME%TYPE
```

Is there an equivalent operator in Postgres? (I'm using 9.4.1)

Comment: Yes - [postgresql also has %TYPE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/plpgsql-declarations.html#PLPGSQL-DECLARATION-TYPE) but not in table creation AFAIK.

Comment: We are using it in PL/SQL. I actually copied/pasted this question's contents from a question asking the same thing about MySQL. Shame on me, I know.

Comment: So you want to know if you can use `%TYPE` in `[plpgsql]`, which is PostgreSQL's almost-but-not-quite version of Oracle's PL/SQL, correct? And please update your question with the version of PostgreSQL you're using. Thanks.

Comment: You can create an entire table like another: CREATE TABLE newtable ( LIKE anothertable);

Comment: See the link StuartLC added.