# Its possible apply COPY TYPE in CREATE TYPE name_type?

Tags: postgresql, postgres15

postgres 15 show error apply in this manner error  email users.email%TYPE

```
CREATE TYPE userx AS (
        email users.email%type, 
        name user.name%type, 
        area users.profession%type);
```

in tried replicated for oracle syntax

```
Type  tipo_r  IS RECORD (id  number(3),
                   nombre  varchar(10),
                   salario  emp.salary%type);
```

Comment: Apparently not: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30383317/is-there-a-postgres-equivalent-to-oracle-type, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57487156/how-can-i-use-type-in-postgres-type-definition